# Knockout 3+ How do you bind a jquery mobile radio button to knockout?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

https://jsfiddle.net/9L8r9etf/2/

I've been trying a few different methods, but this is the closest I've gotten. for some reason this.checked is always true.

javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // This hack for knockout v3
        // set the dom element to a checkbox and initialize it (for jquerymobile)
        var checkbox = $(element);
        // let jquerymobile enhance the element
        checkbox.removeAttr('data-role');
        // make it so
        checkbox.checkboxradio();
        //register change event to update the model on changes to the dom
        checkbox.on('change', function (e) {
                if(this.checked)
            valueAccessor()(this.value);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // update the checked binding, important for correct radio button behaviour.
        //ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update(element, valueAccessor);
        //ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // This hack for knockout v3

        // and refresh the element (for jquerymobile)
        var checkbox = $(element);
        checkbox.checkboxradio('refresh');
        checkbox.prop("checked", valueAccessor()()).checkboxradio("refresh");

    }
};

var ViewModel = function(repeat) {
        var self = this;
        self.testa = ko.observable(true);
    self.test = ko.observable("dyn");
    if(repeat){
    self.subView = ko.observable(new ViewModel(false));
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(true));
```

html:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
  <label><input type="radio" value="inp" name="inpdynout2" checked data-bind="jqmChecked:test"/> inp</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="dyn" name="inpdynout2" data-bind="jqmChecked:test" /> dyn</label>
  <label><input type="radio" value="out" name="inpdynout2" data-bind="jqmChecked:test" /> out</label>
</fieldset>
<hr/>
x <span data-bind="text:test"></span><br/>
```

I understand that in knockout 3, you need to create your own event listeners instead of using checked.update, but I've not been able to work out how to use it with the original checked binding.

I would like the binding to act as much as like the knockout 3 vanilla binding as much as possible, as we have already been bitten by bugs where a custom binding wasn't complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could share some details about the bugs you mentioned in the question. Anyway, to keep the checked attr synchronized, i would use something like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRadio = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var value = valueAccessor(),
      valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
    if (!valueUnwrapped) {
      var checkedValue = $('input[name=' + element.name + ']:checked').val();
      value(checkedValue);
    }
    return ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()); // for dependency
    if (!!$.data(element, "mobile-checkboxradio")) {
      (element.value !== valueUnwrapped) ? $(element).removeAttr("checked"): $(element).attr("checked", "checked");
      $(element).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
  }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.test = ko.observable(); // initialized by attr
  self.test2 = ko.observable("dyn"); // initialized by ko
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.options.deferUpdates = true;
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout" checked data-bind="checkedValue:'inp', jqmRadio:test"> inp</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout" data-bind="checkedValue:'dyn', jqmRadio:test"> dyn</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout" data-bind="checkedValue:'out', jqmRadio:test"> out</label>
      </fieldset>
      <hr/>
      <br/>
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout2" data-bind="checkedValue:'inp', jqmRadio:test2"> inp</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout2" data-bind="checkedValue:'dyn', jqmRadio:test2"> dyn</label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="inpdynout2" data-bind="checkedValue:'out', jqmRadio:test2"> out</label>
      </fieldset>
      <hr/>
      <pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are the differences between using deferUpdates or not? won't that affect other things in my application? (also we arn't on a version where that is available yet)

Can you comment on what $.data(element, "mobile-checkboxradio") is for?

and 

$(element).attr("checked", "checked"); vs $(element).prop("checked", element.value === unwrapped)

Comment: The bugs mentioned in the question are mostly internal things for custom bindings that others have written that are unrelated. People saying in the documentation that they work for checkboxes / radio buttons but only end up working for checkboxes etc. either due to lack of testing or change of semantics between versions.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: 1) deferUpdates; i just tested this against failure, if you don't use it, simply omit the line. 2) $.data(element, "mobile-checkboxradio" is to test if JQM already created the widget, to avoid the error "checkboxradio is not an instance". 3) checked: you are already using this in your example code, probably you get the form data and you submit/store the form data, so by using attr the form data will match the ko checkedValue binding (not the case by using prop or nothing - check it out inspecting element).

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: sadly, the widely acclaimed knockout backward-compatibility has been broken from ko v2.x to 3.x by requiring to change in markup the checked binding with checkedValue, i was also unhappy about that decision.

Answer (score -1):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmCheckedRadio = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // set the dom element to a checkbox and initialize it (for jquerymobile)
        var checkbox = $(element);
        // let jquerymobile enhance the element
        checkbox.removeAttr('data-role');
        // make it so
        checkbox.checkboxradio();

        checkbox.on('change', function (e) {
            if ($(this).prop( "checked")) {//this is returning true always.
                valueAccessor()(this.value);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // update the checked binding, i.e., check or uncheck the checkbox
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); 
        // and refresh the element (for jquerymobile)
        $(element).prop("checked", element.value === unwrapped).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
};
```

This works following the knockout 3 semantics of multiple radio buttons being bound to a single observable, but uses their attribute value as opposed to checkValue.

It has not been tested for checkboxes, or for boolean radio buttons.

If you need dynamic amounts of radiobuttons it should work ok with that as well.